# How to hide HTML code in response status in REST web service

Tags: html, web-services, rest, httpresponse

I am new to REST web service.
Do anyone know how to hide or remove the HTML code in response status in REST web service?
Now in HTTP response I got the response status + HTML code.
Is it because of Error or Exception ?

thanks

Comment: What platform are you using for your REST service?  Are you only seeing this HTML when the status code is a 400 or 500?

Comment: hi Darrel Miller,   I have found the problem.I use linux and Netbean with java. Thanks